# Setting the height of a devexpress mvc Gridview combo box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, combobox, devexpress

I am using a DEvExpress mvc grid with a few combo boxes and I was wondering how I can set the maximum/minimum height (in a number of rows) of the drop down section.

For example can I set the rows visible before you have to scroll or even if there is only one row of data for the drop down height to be set to a certain number of rows.

The current code for the combo I have now is

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(edtSettings =>
{
    edtSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "employeeDetailsGridEditField";
    edtSettings.Name = "DepartmentID";
    edtSettings.Width = 350;
    //edtSettings.Height = 200; 
    //THIS sets the height of the initial control not the drop down part
    edtSettings.Properties.TextField = "DepartmentName";
    edtSettings.Properties.ValueField = "DepartmentID";
    edtSettings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);
    edtSettings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
    edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;
}).BindList(Model.DepartmentList).Bind(Model.EmployeeSingle.DefaultDepartmentID).GetHtml()
```

Is there a property for the drop down section height?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this one please?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ComboBoxProperties.DropDownRows](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsComboBoxProperties_DropDownRowstopic) property to get or set the number of list items displayed within the editor's scrollable dropdown window simultaneously:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(edtSettings =>
{
    //...
    edtSettings.Properties.DropDownRows = 5; // default is 7 
    //...        
}).BindList(Model.DepartmentList).Bind(Model.EmployeeSingle.DefaultDepartmentID).GetHtml()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it does not seem to work. The department drop down mentioned above only has 2 rows of data in it and I have added the line of code you mentioned and it is still only showing 2 rows